# Javascript's getBBox() provides a box that is taller than its content text. Why?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using D3.js to draw some text ("100%") on an SVG Container.

Now I'm trying to figure out the dimensions of the bounding box around that text.

This is how I do it:

```
      var label = svgContainer.append("text")
        .attr("x", 200)
        .attr("y", 200)
        .text("100%")
        .attr("font-family", "Courier New")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .attr("font-size", "10px")
        .attr("fill", "black");
        .attr("transform", function(d){
            var bb = this.getBBox();
            console.log("bb.width = ", bb.width);
            console.log("bb.height = ", bb.height);
            return "translate(0, 0)";
          }
        );
```

Not only does this draw the string "100%" on my screen, but in the console.log, it also outputs the width and height of the bounding box (24 & 11.5 respectively!);

Now I want to visualize the aforementioned bounding box on the screen. So before the code above, I prepend the following code:

```
        var rect = svgContainer.append("rect")
          .attr("x", 200)
          .attr("y", 200-11.5)
          .attr("width", 24)
          .attr("height", 11.5)
          .attr("fill", "pink");
```

When I run this altered code, I expect to see a pink bounding box around the "100%" string. But I see the following instead!

[image]

Why is the pink bounding box taller than the text? I need to get the dimensions  of the actual bounding-box of the text -- not something taller than it. How do I do that?

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XoVSZwTBNXhdKKJKkYWn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. You are only using the height and width fields of the bounding box.  You should be also taking into account the x and y attributes of the bounding box - as @Gilsha correctly pointed out.  When you do adjust for the x and y, you'll see the box sits a little lower:

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("my_svg_widget");

    
var bbox = svg.getElementById("test").getBBox();

var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
rect.setAttribute("x", bbox.x);
rect.setAttribute("y", bbox.y);
rect.setAttribute("width", bbox.width);
rect.setAttribute("height", bbox.height);
rect.setAttribute("fill", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)");
svg.appendChild(rect);
```

```html
<svg id="my_svg_widget" width="300" height="300" style="border-style:solid;border-color:purple;border-width: 2px;">
  <text id="test" x="100" y="100" font-family="Courier New" font-weight="bold" font-size="50px">100%</text>
</svg>
```

2. This brings us to the second reason.  The bounding box returned by `getBBox()` is not the tight bounding box around the glyphs.  It includes the full em-box height of the text - including allowance for ascenders (tallest characters in font) and descenders (lowest below baseline).

You can see what I mean if we include some of those characters in the text element.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("my_svg_widget");

    
var bbox = svg.getElementById("test").getBBox();

var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
rect.setAttribute("x", bbox.x);
rect.setAttribute("y", bbox.y);
rect.setAttribute("width", bbox.width);
rect.setAttribute("height", bbox.height);
rect.setAttribute("fill", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)");
svg.appendChild(rect);
```

```html
<svg id="my_svg_widget" width="300" height="300" style="border-style:solid;border-color:purple;border-width: 2px;">
  <text id="test" x="100" y="100" font-family="Courier New" font-weight="bold" font-size="50px">&#193;100%&#x2563;</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes. I see what you are saying here as shown here: https://plnkr.co/edit/FbONItNSfrcjMq2BBvc5?p=preview. So how do I get the tight bounding-box around just the glyphs that I'm using (without the highest possible ascenders and lowest possible descenders)?

Comment: @SaqibAli There is no mechanism to do that in SVG. What Paul has shown you is the best you can do.

Comment: This might not be applicable to SVG, but with canvas I had to iterate over every pixel from left to right + top to bottom looking for the first non-alpha bit (then the same thing from the bottom to the top)... That was the only way I could figure out how to accurately get the tight height measurement of what chars are actually displayed.  Obviously this has performance implications if you do this "onpress"...

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use bounding box `x` and `y` attributes. Use below code.

```
var label = self.svgContainer.append("text")
  .attr("x", 200)
  .attr("y", 200)
  .text("100%")
  .attr("font-family", "Courier New")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold")
  .attr("font-size", "10px")
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("transform", function(d){
      var bb = this.getBBox();
      self.svgContainer.insert("rect","text")
        .attr("x", bb.x)
        .attr("y", bb.y)
        .attr("width", bb.width)
        .attr("height", bb.height)
        .attr("fill", "pink");
      return "translate(0, 0)";
  });
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.svgContainer = d3.select("#my_svg_widget");

    console.log("Hello!");
    

    var label = self.svgContainer.append("text")
      .attr("x", 200)
      .attr("y", 200)
      .text("100%")
      .attr("font-family", "Courier New")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("font-size", "10px")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("transform", function(d){
          var bb = this.getBBox();
          self.svgContainer.insert("rect","text")
            .attr("x", bb.x)
            .attr("y", bb.y)
            .attr("width", bb.width)
            .attr("height", bb.height)
            .attr("fill", "pink");
          return "translate(0, 0)";
      });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body ng-controller="MyController as mycontroller">
    <svg id="my_svg_widget" width="300" height="300" style="border-style:solid;border-color:purple;border-width: 2px;">
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using the width/height from getBBox() but as I illustrated in my question and in the Plunker, that width/height is incorrect. See the image of the pink rectangle not fitting the text properly.

Comment: yes. You are right regarding the width and height config. But the problem is with the y attribute you have set to the rectangle.

Comment: When you directly take the y attribute and reduce the height, you are not considering the font size of text. So you can use the bounding box x, y attributes instead of error prone calculation.

Comment: No, that's not correct. Did you not see the plunker? Yes, I'm actually hardcoding in the values of the height/width of the pink box for illustrative purposes. However, those hardcoded values match exactly what the getBbox() returns. So the hardcoding is irrelevant! I just do it this way for illustrative purposes so I can draw the pink rectangle before I draw the text.

Comment: More pointedly, getBBox() returns a height of 11.5. Whereas the text is clearly less than 11.5 pixels high. So why is it lying?